# Prove that $\int_{\gamma} f(z)\ dz = 0$ for any closed contour $\gamma$ in the region $G$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Prove that if $f$ is analytic in a region $G$ then $\int_{\gamma} f(z)\ dz = 0$ for any closed contour $\gamma$ on the region $G$.

I have proved this result for open disk but fail to generalize it for any region. Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is only valid for simply connected regions.

Comment: Would you please explain why? I have much difficulty in understanding it. Please help me.

Comment: You are aware that $\int_C dz/z=2\pi i$ when $C$ is the unit circle?

Comment: Yes I know it. Actually I want to know that what is the special characteristics of simply connected domain for having some smooth properties.

Comment: If you have Stein's *Complex Analysis* at hand, check Theorem 5.1 in Chapter 3. The main point is: in a simply connected region all curves that start from $z_0$ and ends at $z_1$ can be transformed continuously into each other, thus equating the integral of any holomorphic function along them.

Comment: No I have neither Stein complex analysis in my hand nor I have a mobile which supports pdf formats.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown What if the $G$ is not specified? Like in here: [How to prove that $\int_\gamma ze^{z^2} dz = 0$ for any closed curve $\gamma$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/358047)